# How should I remove a patch of colour-cast?

Tags: color-correction

The photo below has a distinct patch of purplish colour, in the area within the yellow oval. It's a shame because I like the picture. I think it must have been caused by low morning sunlight catching the lens.

What would be a good way to remove it? I think it's only really visible on the bronze frog, so basically, I want to apply the rule "if you see this purplish hue in this region, shift it towards this correct colour".

Or something like that, I am not so familiar with these operations.

I have Pixelmator Pro and Photos for macOS at my disposal; I don't think that the latter's going to help much though.

How would you try to correct this?

[image: photo with colour-cast]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difficult part is selecting the area you want to correct. I don't know your software, but in Photoshop here is how I would do it:

Set the magic wand tolerence to about 10. Repeatedly select using shift-click to add  more to the selection. Do this until you have roughly selected the area.

[image]

Feather the selection so you don't have sharp edges that will be noticable after the next operation. I used about 30 pixels.

Use the color balance tool: less blue, less red, more green.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I did this - I am sure someone more expert could get better results, but it's a great improvement.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably best done with a brush tool. Sample the color of the surrounding statue, set the brush to Color mode and brush over the discolored area.

Comment: This is by far the better method. You can even let the brush be less than 100% strength just to leave little colour hints in some places. Here's a quick attempt, leaving some hints in & also pushing clarity/contrast which I think helps too - https://i.stack.imgur.com/mdJUP.jpg